# Is there a minimum time to be mining a pool to have any results?

Tags: cgminer, pool-payout-methods, time

For example if mining with Deepbit is there a minimum time one must run cgminer to have anything added to their Deepbit account balance?

Comment: The duration of 1 share?

Answer (score 1):

Deepbit allows PPS (pay per share) or Prop (proportional) mining. Under PPS, you get credited for each share you mine. Under Prop, you get credited after the pool finds a block, with the 25 BTC split proportionally among the miners based on how many shares they have. Since Deepbit has 1% of the total hashrate (according to [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/pools)), on average it will take 100 * 10 min = 16 hours to find a block, though I stress this is only an average and variance can be very high. So if you choose Prop, you'll get paid every 16 hours, on average.

Comment: It should be clarified that you don't need to mine for 16 hours - you can mine for 1 minute and you'll still be rewarded for this minute when the pool finds a block. Of course, the reward for a minute of mining will be miniscule, possibly lower than it would make sense to withdraw.